# How do share Session Data between two frameworks?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, laravel-4

I have one Cake App and one Laravel App, running on the same domain.

On my Laravel App I have a route to login users from the Cake App.
This Cake App has all the data that I need on the $_SESSION.

The problem is that I can't access the $_SESSION data on Laravel.

The Cake app's Session Name is "CAKEPHP".

My Test code is below:

```
$original_session_name = session_name('CAKEPHP');
session_start();
var_dump($original_session_name);
var_dump(session_name());
dd($_SESSION);
```

Which echoes:

```
string(9) "PHPSESSID"
string(7) "CAKEPHP"
array(0) { }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Why cant you access the $_SESSION data in Laravel? What happens when you do `dd($_SESSION)`?

Comment: When I just do `dd($_SESSION);` it returns undefined.  When I do `session_start(); dd($_SESSION);` it returns a blank array

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what happened, but I've found the answer.
I will leave it here, for anyone with the same problem.

All I did was to name the session before starting one.
On my case it's a CAKEPHP application so:

```
session_name('CAKEPHP');
session_start();
dd($_SESSION);
```

Works great. In my Laravel app I have access to all session data store on the Cake application.

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to manage this.

Laravel does a lot of magic behind the scenes which breaks _SESSION and _COOKIE variables.

I would instead recommend that you build a form on the Cake app, which posts some sort-of key to the Laravel app that is stored in the database and Laravel can verify that key, allowing the user to `Auth::login()`

There are rather hack-y ways to access those session variables, but you're going to have a bad time. [View the thread on the Laravel Forums](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=13064)